# How to find items having the higher number of similar tags?

Tags: mysql, search, sphinx

I have a relatively large database with 10 mln items and 25 mln tags-to-item relations and I'm looking for the fastest way to find items that have the highest number of similar tags, e.g. item 1 has tags `a,b,c`, item 2 `d,b,c`, item 3 `d,e,c`, here for item 1, item 2 has 2 similar tags, and item 3 - 1.

I've tried native mysql search like this:

```
select itemid, count(*) tags 
from tags2items 
where tagid in (4,173,316,1219,4193,18462,18652,18871,19495,19735) 
group by itemid 
order by tags desc limit 10;
```

and it takes 16 seconds, having a query with self-join would presumably take even longer.

I'm using Sphinx for full-text searching with tag as an MVA and a query like

```
SELECT id,(mva=7)+(mva=33)+(mva=129) as sorter 
from index 
where mva IN (7,33,129) 
order by sorter desc limit 10;
```

takes about a second.

Is there any way to make this search faster? Maybe with redis? The db changes infrequently, so it's ok to have some long running process preparing this fast tag db.

Unless absolutely necessary, I wouldn't like to add java-based stuff like elasticsearch.

Comment: Isn't this basically what geneticists do? I'd find out how they do it and copy that.

Comment: Don't use **count(*)**. It is faster if you count by a column that has an index like **count(itemid)**

Comment: You can create index on tagid and itemid

Comment: @nacho I cannot replicate this assertion

Comment: Why don't you use full text field instead of the MVA? You can then utilize all the power it gives including expression based ranking and a wide range of factors. In your case perhaps hit_rank will work best.

Comment: @ManticoreSearch I've actually tried this. I've put a space concatenated list of tags in a separate field, then tried searching over this field. The speed was good, but it gave no results for items that had a unique set of tags. The "quorum operator" kind of helped, but it all felt very hacky. I'd rather have some dedicated software that was specifically designed for it.

Comment: Well if want something 'specifically' designed, the closest is probably a graph database https://www.google.com/search?q=graph+database - tags can be modeled in a graph system. But even then it could perhaps be considered 'hacky'.  Using Sphinx/Manticores inverted index (ie using field, rather than Attribute) seems a better fit to be honest.